# PHP Comapring Array contains same string, excluding identical rows

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$a = array (

[0] => 0
[1] => 1
[2] => 2
[3] => 3

)

$b = array (

[0] => 2
[1] => 1
[2] => 3
[3] => 4

)
```

If I want to count that same object, I could use `array_intersect`--> `echo count(array_intersect($a,$b));`.
Which returns: `3`

However, I would like to exclude their identical rows:

```
$a = array (

[0] => 0
[1] => 1 //Both are the same that I would like to exclude
[2] => 2
[3] => 3

)

$b = array (

[0] => 2
[1] => 1 //Both are the same that I would like to exclude
[2] => 3
[3] => 4

)
```

Which will only returns `2`.

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference your first and second example?

Comment: @JohnCartwright It is same, but both array `$a` and `$b` have the identical row : `[1] => 1`, which I would like exclude from the return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loop, can't think of anything else right now.

```
$identical = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
    if(isset($b[$i]) && $a[$i] === $b[$i]) {
        $identical++;
    }
}
$count = count(array_intersect($a,$b)) - $identical;
$count = ($count < 0) ? 0 : $count;
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$a = array (0,1,2,3);
$b = array (2,1,3,4);

$final = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b));

print "total : ". count($final);
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried  but it returns 5? [code](http://www.jamiephan.net/MyStuff/so/test.php)

Comment: Yes, this code combines the array and remove duplicate values, then the result of the count would be 5.